# Bash Script save value without creating temp files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, stdout

i have a bash script with following code :

```
#!/bin/bash
cat chars.txt | sed 's/.*\(...\)/\1/' > lastchars.txt
aws ses send-email --from Email --destination Email --message file://lastchars.txt
rm lastchars.txt
```

and my idea is to find a solution to make the same functionality, but without creating Temp file. I've heard and read about **STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR**, but do not know if this will help me, maybe someone have ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

In simple way:

```
aws ses send-email --from Email --destination Email --message "$(sed 's/.*\(...\)/\1/' chars.txt)"
```

Comment: ye i know , but it's just a simple sample , i have a largest contain whom needs store in memory not on temp files.

Comment: @Andrej, then , extend your question and describe that conditions.

Answer (score 2):

If stdin is not used by the command then the "file" `/dev/stdin` can be used:

```
cat chars.txt | sed 's/.*\(...\)/\1/' | aws ses send-email --from Email --destination Email --message file:///dev/stdin
```

otherwise the `<()` will create a pipe and return the name

```
aws ses send-email --from Email --destination Email --message file://<(cat chars.txt | sed 's/.*\(...\)/\1/')
```

On the filesystem these two options look something like this:

```
ls -l /dev/stdin <(echo)

lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 15 Jun 26  2015 /dev/stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
prw------- 1 user user  0 Oct 12 16:01 /tmp/zshuOs5sV
```